# How do I autofilter table contents and count resulting rows?

Tags: excel, visible, autofilter, vba

I am trying to count the instances of an event for both days of the week and hours of the day (to be graphed separately) with VBA. The date/time stamp is in this format: "2/28/2014 20:32"

Example:
    AppID = 14329   
DateCreated = 2/28/14 20:55 
Day = Friday    
Hour = 20:55

What I have going on right now is copying the data to a new column and setting the date format to "dddd" so it would display as "Sunday" etc. From there I am autofiltering for each day of the week and counting the resulting visible cells. This is working with this code:

```
With Range("C2:C" & LR)
                .AutoFilter

                .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Sunday"
                        cCnt = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(3) _
                        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count
                            For Each cell In Range("C2:C" & cCnt)
                            Sun = Sun + 1
                            Next

                .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Monday"
                        cCnt = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(3) _
                        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count
                            For Each cell In Range("C2:C" & cCnt)
                            Mon = Mon + 1
                            Next
```

...etc.

However, my issue is counting the events by hour. I am trying to do it similarly by copying the date/time to a new column and setting the format to "h:mm;@" and autofiltering by hour with this code:

```
With Range("D2:D" & LR)
            .AutoFilter

            .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="10:??"
                        cCnt = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(4) _
                        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count
                            For Each cell In Range("D2:D" & cCnt)
                            time(10) = time(10) + 1
                            Next
```

...etc.

This isn't working and I can't figure out why. I've tried changing the criteria1 to various syntax, adding a second criteria parameter and am stumped why this method would work for the first go around but not the second when both columns are derived from the same original data. I have also tried changing the data to a different time format (just "hh" etc).

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, try changing `10:??` to `10:*`

Comment: Thanks Portland, I have tried that as well as `10*`. The results are slightly different but still not correct, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How Excel stores Dates & Times:**

Excel uses a 'serial' number system to store dates (first day is January 1, 1900):

> `01/01/1900 = 1`
>
> `01/02/1900 = 2`

Time is represented by anything after the decimal (noon is .5 because it's halfway through the day):

> `01/01/1900 12:00 = 1.5`
>
> `01/02/1900 15:00 = 2.625`

If you filter based on values, it's important to be aware of this.

**Include this code in your module:**

```
    Public Function GetDay(ByVal inputDate As String) As String

        GetDay = WeekdayName(Weekday(inputDate))

    End Function


    Public Function GetHour(ByVal inputDate As Range) As String
        
        GetHour = Format(inputDate.Value, "Medium Time")

    End Function
```

**Now use these functions on your worksheet and AutoFill:**

[image: Raw Data Table]
[image: Table Step 1]
[image: Table Step 2]
[image: Final Table]

**In your existing code modify the following:**

```
    With Range("D2")

        .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="10:?? PM"

            'If criteria didn't match anything, cCnt is equal to 1 (because header rows are visible and counted)
            cCnt = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(4).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count

            If cCnt > 1 Then
            
                For Each cell In Range("D2:D" & cCnt)
                    Hour10PM = Hour10PM + 1
                Next
            
            End If

            MsgBox (Hour10PM & " matches for 10:00PM to 10:59PM")
            
            
        .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="11:?? PM"

            cCnt = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(4).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count

            If cCnt > 1 Then
            
                For Each cell In Range("D2:D" & cCnt)
                    Hour11PM = Hour11PM + 1
                Next
                
            End If
            
            MsgBox (Hour11PM & " matches for 11:00PM to 11:59PM")
            
    End With
```

**Additional Notes:**

Obviously I just gave a snippet of code, but the idea would be that you could split and keep count of every hour.  Then to graph it should be simple.

Comment: Perfect, worked like a charm. Thanks so much for all the detail, Bobby!